# Grunt less sourcemaps appear empty in Chrome dev tools

Tags: gruntjs, less, source-maps

In a single page application, I have a main less file called `styles.less` that contains imports to other less files in the current directory as well as in different directories. The imports are the following:

```
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/less/datepicker.less";
@import "../bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.less";
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "../bower_components/font-awesome/less/font-awesome";
@import "../bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui";
@import "gritter";
@import "animate";
@import "animate-delay";
@import "toggles";
@import "chosen";
@import "droid";
@import "roboto";
@import "bootstrap-override";
@import "fullcalendar";
@import "style-default";
... custom styles begin here ...
```

And I have the following grunt task file that uses grunt-contrib-less:

```
less: {
  main: {
    options: {
      strictImports: true,
      compress: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapURL: styles.min.css.map
    },
    files: [{
      src: "css/styles.less",
      dest: "dist/css/styles.css"
    }]
  }
}
```

The sourcemap file gets generated and it seems to be loaded correctly because when I inspect an element style in the Chrome developer tools, instead of having references like: `styles.min.css:1543` now I get references like: `style-default.less:5`, `chosen.less:57`, etc.
The problem I'm having is when I click the reference it takes me to the corresponding file but it's empty, all of them.

In the `style-default.less:5` reference, for example, Chrome shows that the url is: http://example.com/css/css/style-default.less; but of course, that URL and files does not exist since all the styles have been minified and packed into styles.min.css.

What am I missing in the grunt task above?

Comment: See [outputSourceFiles](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#outputsourcefiles) option.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: adding that option and setting it to true solved the issue! Thanks for the help.